# Scroll to top on component render

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

How to set it up that when a component is rendered it should scroll to top of the window ? I have a table . When the table componenet is rendered it should come to the top of screen and not in middle .It is possible in javascript ?? But how using React

```
function ManageProcess({ checkStatus, actions, form, signal }) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(initialState.checkStatus);

  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    actions.setSubmitted();
    actions.resetChecks();
    actions.startCheck({
      ...constants.START_CHECK,
      dependent: constants.INITIAL_CHECK
    });

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (form.submitted) {
      setStatus(checkStatus);
    } else {
      setStatus(initialState.checkStatus);
    }
  }, [checkStatus]);

  return (
    <div  className="container ">
      <Table responsive className="tablestyle">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="tdt1">Status</th>
            <th className="tdt2">Diagnostic Steps</th>
            <th>Result</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {status.length > 0 ? (
            status.map(element => {
              return (
                <CheckContainer
                  key={element.id}
                  status={element}
                  signal={signal}
                />
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <>nope</>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
  return (
    <div>MyComponent</div>
  );
}
```

In react u can try also [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll)

Comment: not working . I want the table to start from top of the page

Comment: I do not understand your question then. You want to *scroll to top* or *move component to top* or both?

Comment: move component to top of page .The table doesn't appear from top of the screen . It appears after some text which I have added . I want the text to go up and table to be in front and then we can scroll up to the text if we want .Like scroll element to view in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean by 'rendered'. If you want to scroll to top everytime the component is rendered or re-rendered you should scroll to top inside render function

`render() {
window.scrollTo(0,0);
// first argument is x-coordinate and second is y-coordinate
  return(
// your JSX
) 
}`

if you are using functions instead of classes, doing it anywhere before render will do the job.

if you want to scroll in the first mount and not on subsequent rerenders, you can scroll to top inside `componentDidMount` method

Comment: The table doesn't appear from top of the screen . It appears after some text which I have added . I want the text to go up and table to be in front  and then we can scroll up to the text if we want .

Comment: I want to move the component to top of window on loading

Comment: It was not clear from your question. If you know the height of your text, you can scroll to that height exactly and your table will scroll to top. To get the position of your table create a ref `this.tableRef = React.createRef()` in constructor. Assign that ref to your table `<table ref={this.tableRef}/>` then inside your `componentDidMount` do this `this.projectMap.current.getBoundingClientRect()` it will give you `y-coordinate` which you can scroll to using window.scrollTo function.

Comment: Can you give example code .. this is bit confusing . I have my text and table in different components

Comment: <div ref={tableref} className="container ">
  const tableref = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const rect = tableref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollTo(0, rect);} . I tried this but it is not working

Comment: wiindow.scrollTo(rect.x, rect.y) 

Also, try using it outside useEffect maybe, since you wanna do it on every render

Comment: Not working  .I want the table to be on the screen and text to go up . I tried this  const tableref = React.createRef();
  const moveTableToView = () => {
    const rect = tableref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollTo(rect.x, rect.y);
  };  return (
    <div ref={tableref} className="container ">
      {moveTableToView}

Comment: return ( <div ref={tableref} className="container "> {moveTableToView()}</div>)

notice the brackets `moveTableToView()` you need to call the function